# Can TextRecognize read digits?

Tags: ocr

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226971/143605), I tried `TextRecognize` to read single digits. But it doesn't recognize a single digit, even though the digits are clearly readable.

For example, this [image] is not recognized.

This is my code:

```
digits = ImagePartition[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLncR.png"], 50];
Map[TextRecognize, digits, {2}]
```

Comment: If we could do this: Map[TextRecognize[#,Range[0,9]]&, digits, {2}] it would be more likely to work. But we can't. I have asked Wolfram developers for this, maybe you should too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
(* Get your image *)
digits = ImagePartition[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLncR.png"], 50];

(* Remove Borders and Binarize *)
d1 = Binarize[ImageCrop[#, 37], .5] & /@ Flatten@digits;

(* Keep only images with content (blanks affect the OCR) *)
d2 = Select[d1, Min@ImageData@# == 0 &];

(* Assemble as a line and "read" *)
TextRecognize@ImageAssemble@d2
(*
-> "64776958729385431752328231"
*)
```

**Edit**

The following will reassemble your original image (but cleaner)

```
tr    = TextRecognize@ImageAssemble@d2;
posd2 = Flatten@Position[d1, x_ /; Min@ImageData@x == 0, {1}];
tp2   = Thread@List[posd2, Characters@tr];
(d1[[#[[1]]]] = Graphics[Text[Style[#[[2]], Large]], ImageSize -> 37]) & /@ tp2;
ia    = ImageAssemble@Partition[ImageCrop[#, 39] & /@ d1, 9]; 
ia1   = Map[ImageCrop[#, ImageDimensions@ia/3 + 3] &, 
            ImagePartition[ia, ImageDimensions@ia/{3, 3}], {2}];

GraphicsRow[{ImageAssemble@ia1, ImageAssemble@digits}]
```

[image]

Comment: If I try `TextRecognize@d2[[1]]`, it doesn't work. Neither works for me `TextRecognize@ImageAssemble[d2[[1 ;; 2]]]`, but   `TextRecognize@ImageAssemble[d2[[1 ;; 3]]]` does. Do you know any minimun requirements for `TextRecognize`?

Comment: @FJRA Nope, it's a trial and error thing. I found that you need several chars in a row, with little blank space in between for the thing to work in a reliable way

Comment: Yes, doing some test, I would have expected something like this to work: `TextRecognize[Rasterize[5]]`. And it seems that image size matters a lot: `TextRecognize[Rasterize[50868, ImageSize -> 300]]` vs `TextRecognize[Rasterize[50868]]`. Something else to take care when using `TextRecognize`.

Comment: @FJRA TextRecognize[] is not a full blown OCR implemententation, but a nice testbed for exploring some ideas or solving simple image conversion problems. I'd not use it in a "real" problem environment.

Comment: but very nice to play with it!