# Applying TextRecognize on alpha-numerical table

Tags: ocr

From time to time I have to extract data from scanned papers or rasterized PDFs. Imagine a table of the following kind (but much longer):

[image]

A naive application of `TextRecognize` on the image fails spectacularly:

```
"OOE-
20B-
70E~
20E-
90E-
70E-
70B-
30B-
30B-
ZOE
.50E+O2
.50E+02
.0OE+02
.O0E+O2
.00E+O2
.OOE+02
18E+O4
.30E+O3
.70E+03
10E+03
```

Did anybody use `TextRecognize` successfully on similar images?

Comment: `TextRecognize` doesn't do it letter by letter, but tries to identify words from a dictionary. This is a known limitation... See [this answer by Arnoud](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919253)

Comment: and "When recognizing formatted numbers, whitespace may cause OCR errors", according to the documentation...

Comment: `TextRecognize` is based on [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), which is free and open source and will give you a lot more flexibility than using `TextRecognize`. For example it lets you constrain the set of characters you are interested in.  That said, some time ago I tried to use it to read a huge matrix of 0s and 1s (again from an old paper), and ended up needing to do many manual corrections in each row ...  It's probably not worth the time.

Comment: Interesting this Tesseract. I saw a simple nice guide for Mac OS [here](http://blog.bobkuo.com/2011/02/installing-and-using-tesseract-2-04-on-mac-os-x-10-6-6-with-homebrew/)

Comment: I wish someone would write an article on how to customize Tesseract for MMA. A while back I went digging and discovered grammar/dictionary files---but I'd have no clue how to customize these, or if the version distributed with MMA would even allow for it.

Comment: Does anyone know if TextRecognize is a closed-source repackaging of Tesseract within Mathematica?  Has anyone discovered any useful undocumented functions that can customize the behavior of this tool?  It would be interesting to use Mma to try to build a mathematical OCR document engine since there's not many other choices  available in this area yet.

Comment: Tesseract data in MacOS here: /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Converters/Tesseract/tessdata

Answer (score 40):

Here is a way of extracting the positions of the various characters in your image by using `ImageCorrelate`.

Define the image to be worked on.

```
image = <your image goes here>
```

Define a set of kernel images to correlate with the image. I use `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,E,.}` scaled to an appropriate size and then rasterised.

```
kernels =
  Map[
    (Style[#, FontSize -> 28, FontWeight -> Bold] // Rasterize // 
    ColorNegate // Binarize) &,
    Join[Range[0, 9], {"+", "-", "E", "."}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Prepare the image for use in `ImageCorrelate`. Adding 0.01 to the 0 background avoids problems with it being “detected” - try omitting this step to see what happens.

```
imageneg = image // ColorNegate // ImageAdd[#, 0.01] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compute the `CosineDistance` image correlation for each kernel image. Threshold the results to detect instances of each kernel image, and Dilate the resulting small bright detections so you can easily see them.

```
imagecorrels = 
  Map[
    (ImageCorrelate[imageneg, #, CosineDistance] // ColorNegate //
     Binarize[#, 0.85] &) &,
    kernels
  ];

MapThread[Column[{#1, #2}] &, {Dilation[#, 3] & /@ imagecorrels, kernels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The results are very good for this set of kernel images. However, some of the “+” and “-“ are missed, which is probably because their kernel images differ too much from what appears in the image to be processed, and the “.” at the bottom of the image are missed, but this looks like an “edge effect” that would go away if you didn’t crop the image so tightly. Also, the “I” of “SI” is mistaken for a “1”.

The image processing could be tweaked to improve this performance. For instance, you could make the correlation results "compete" with each other to determine the "detection" at each image location - i.e. identify before detect - rather than simply threshold the correlations independently.

The locations of the detected image kernels could then be post-processed to create a representation of your image in terms of kernel images.

Comment: Nice (and got the +1 when you posted), but it's a bit unfortunate that we need to write our OCR engine from scratch (what you practically did here!) because `TextRecognize` won't allow configuring Tesserract (the engine it uses) with enough flexibility.  One important step in your solution is restricting the possible set of characters.  Tesserract has options for this, but `TextRecognize` doesn't expose them.

Comment: I have just checked what happens when you include the whole alphabet by using `Join[Range[0,9],CharacterRange["A","Z"],{"+","-","."}]`. “B” detects “8” as well as “B”, and similarly “I” detects “1” as well as “I”, but otherwise there are no false alarms or missed detections of alphabetic characters. I haven't checked, but I assume that the false alarm problem can be fixed by forcing the detections to "compete" with each other, as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 30):

I get perfect reading using Tesseract using pagesegmode value 6.

[image]

I did this test after [install Tesseract](http://emop.tamu.edu/node/45)

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Run["/usr/local/bin/tesseract hex.png hex -psm 6 "]
```

on as hex.png

[image]

and get

[image]

with no need to restrict character set (you can see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for))

The only mistake are between 0 and O that can be easily corrected as @belisarius shows [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18971/2266).

### Update

Now let's do it inside Mathematica. In [this post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/125919;jsessionid=CBDCC6775C42888934B5A9148EF014C5.wlp2?p_p_auth=4qP2JKvL) from Wolfram Community, Ilian Gachevski shows me how to control page segmentation from inside Mathematica.
It's as simple as:

```
i=Import[hex.png]
TextRecognize[i, "SegmentationMode" -> 6]
```

You can check that options are equivalent executing:

```
Map[Row[#,"  "]&,Image`ExternalOCRDump`$TextRecognizeSegmentationModes,{-2}]//TableForm
```

[image]

With all the comfort of doing all inside Mathematica. Just don't forget that this is an undocumented option.

Comment: Now that's cool. Thanks for figuring that out.

Answer (score 25):

As [I've shown here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4465/193), `TextRecognize[]` is a very basic tool and you usually need to tweak it to fit your needs.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
i = Binarize@ColorNegate@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP6Yt.jpg"];

(* Group the chars line by line *)
ifc = ImageForestingComponents[ColorNegate@i, Automatic, {First@ImageDimensions@i, 1}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[im];
(* A function for dropping blank spaces between letters *)
rule = {h__, {0 ..}, w : {0 ..}, {0 ..}, t__} -> {h, w, w, t};
im[x_] := Transpose[ Transpose[Replace[ifc, Except[x] -> 0, {2}] //. rule] //. rule];

(* French periodic tables are better understood :) *)
tr = TextRecognize[Image[im[#]], Language -> "French"] & /@  Range[2, Max@ifc];

(* Split column blocks *)
strs = {StringTake[#, {1, -17}], StringTake[#, {-16, -9}], StringTake[#, -8]} & /@ tr
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{H} & \text{6.00E-O9} & \text{3.5OE+O2} \\
 \text{H2} & \text{l.20E-09} & \text{4.50E+02} \\
 \text{I-lE} & \text{5.70E-08} & \text{l.00E+02} \\
 \text{C} & \text{4.2OE-l2} & \text{8.00E+O2} \\
 \text{N} & \text{3.90E-l2} & \text{8.00E+02} \\
 0 & \text{3.70E-12} & \text{B.00E+02} \\
 \text{NA} & \text{6.70E-80} & \text{1.18E+04} \\
 \text{MG} & \text{9.3OE-40} & \text{5.30E+03} \\
 \text{SI} & \text{8.3OE-24} & \text{2.70E+03} \\
 \text{S} & \text{4.20E-l4} & \text{1.10E+O3}
\end{array}
\right)$

You may see that there are problems (easy to fix knowing the context) with the number zero and the letter "o", and with the number eight and the letter "B". Also, one letter "H" got read as "I-1"

Now, Here you have a bunch of transformation rules designed to get the correct answer based upon the errors observed in `TextRecognize[]`

```
base = "(\\+|[0-9]|E|\\.|\-)";
MatrixForm[FixedPoint[
  StringReplace[#, {"\[Euro]" -> "E", "I-l" -> "H",
       WordBoundary ~~ "0" ~~ WordBoundary -> "O",
       RegularExpression[base ~~ "O"] :> "$1" ~~ "0",
   RegularExpression[base ~~ "B"] :> "$1" ~~ "8",
       RegularExpression["B" ~~ base] :> "8" ~~ "$1"}] & /@ # &, strs]]
```

- $\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   \text{H} & \text{6.00E-09} & \text{3.50E+02} \\
   \text{H2} & \text{l.20E-09} & \text{4.50E+02} \\
   \text{HE} & \text{5.70E-08} & \text{l.00E+02} \\
   \text{C} & \text{4.20E-l2} & \text{8.00E+02} \\
   \text{N} & \text{3.90E-l2} & \text{8.00E+02} \\
   \text{O} & \text{3.70E-12} & \text{8.00E+02} \\
   \text{NA} & \text{6.70E-80} & \text{1.18E+04} \\
   \text{MG} & \text{9.30E-40} & \text{5.30E+03} \\
   \text{SI} & \text{8.30E-24} & \text{2.70E+03} \\
   \text{S} & \text{4.20E-l4} & \text{1.10E+03}
  \end{array}
  \right)$

For performance issues, please see the companion question [Performance: Collapsing repeated contiguous rows & cols from a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19070/193)

Comment: The periodic table must sound very French :P  This "tweaking" must have taken you a while to get right

Comment: @Szabolcs Not really. As of v8.0 Mma recognized only 6 languages :)

Comment: @belisarius Brilliant! Working like a charm (with some manual tweaking still to do). Is there an easy way to automatically determine the number of table lines in the figure, or do I have to count manually and modify the code accordingly?

Comment: @MarkusRoellig In the code above  `Max@ifc - 1` is the number of lines (I'm updating the code). Glad to hear it works. The only way to avoid the manual tweaks is by having a "trainable" OCR, and Mma doesn't offer that.