# Performance: Collapsing repeated contiguous rows & cols from a matrix

Tags: performance-tuning

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18971/193) I needed to remove contiguous zero-valued cols and rows from a matrix, *leaving only two of them in place*, no matter what the original number was.

I made up this code:

```
m = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, 10^-3], {400, 400}]; 
rule = {h__, {0 ..}, w : {0 ..}, {0 ..}, t__} -> {h, w, w, t};
mClean = Transpose[Transpose[m //. rule] //. rule];
Dimensions@mClean
```

But it is way too slow.
I'm pretty sure this code can be enhanced. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Linked lists - based solution

The real reason for the slowdown seems to be the same as usual for `ReplaceRepeated` - multiple copying of large arrays. I can offer a solution which would still be rule-based, but uses linked lists to avoid the mentioned slowdown. Here are auxiliary functions:

```
zeroVectorQ[x_] := VectorQ[x, IntegerQ] && Total[Unitize[x]] == 0;

toLinkedList[l_List] := Fold[ll[#2, #1] &, ll[], Reverse[l]]

ClearAll[rzvecs];
rzvecs[mat_List] :=  rzvecs[ll[First@#, ll[]], Last@#] &@toLinkedList[mat];

rzvecs[accum_, rest : (ll[] | ll[_, ll[_, ll[]]])] := 
   List @@ Flatten[ll[accum, rest], Infinity, ll];

rzvecs[accum_, ll[head_?zeroVectorQ, ll[_?zeroVectorQ, tail : ll[_?zeroVectorQ, Except[ll[]]]]]] :=
   rzvecs[accum, ll[head, tail]];

rzvecs[accum_, ll[head_?zeroVectorQ, ll[_?zeroVectorQ, tail_]]] :=
   rzvecs[ll[ll[accum, head], head], tail];

rzvecs[accum_, ll[head_, tail_]] := rzvecs[ll[accum, head], tail];
```

Now the main function:

```
removeZeroVectors[mat_] := Nest[Transpose[rzvecs[#]] &, mat, 2]
```

#### Benchmarks

Now the benchmarks:

```
m = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, 10^-3], {600, 600}];
(res = removeZeroVectors[m]); // AbsoluteTiming
(res1 = Transpose[Transpose[m //. rule] //. rule]); // AbsoluteTiming
res == res1

(*
    {0.046875, Null}
    {3.715820, Null}
    True
*)
```

#### Remarks

I have been promoting the uses of linked lists for some time now. In my opinion, in *Mathematica* they allow one to stay of the higher level of abstraction while achieving very decent (for the top-level code) performance. They also allow one to avoid many non-obvious performance-tuning tricks which take time to come up with, and even more time to understand for others. The algorithms expressed with linked lists are usually rather straight-forward and can be directly read off from the code.

Comment: +1, grrreat. I went on the smartless, easily compilable, procedulal road. I really like this one

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. I tried to keep the solution essentially rule-based, that's why I went down this road.

Comment: Should the following return {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}} ? m = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}};

Comment: @halmir No, it should not - the first and last columns are always kept and do not participate in the comparison. In a sense, the OP's original rule serves as a very clear spec.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I see. But OP's description sounds like it should. Probably, OP's rule need to be fixed like the following:rule = {h___, {0 ..}, w : {0 ..}, {0 ..}, t___} -> {h, w, w, t};

Comment: @halmir I would rather take the code as a spec and make the description less ambiguous in this respect - presumably the OP looked at the results of his code and was satisfied with it, just not its speed.

Comment: @halmir Leonid is right, the spec is in my code.

Answer (score 7):

It's not often I get to say this, but this is faster than Leonid's!

```
Clear@rZeroVecs
rZeroVecs[mat_, n_] := (Take[#, Min[n, Length@#]] & /@ Split[mat]) ~Flatten~ 1
```

Here `n` is the number of consecutive zero columns you wish to keep (sort of a generalized version of the question). Use it as:

```
m2 = Nest[rZeroVecs[Transpose@#, 2] &, m, 2];
```

Comment: I wasn't going to produce the fastest solution - otherwise I'd just use `Compile`. I produced the solution which still uses rules *and* is two orders of magnitude faster than the original.

Comment: ...What's the n?

Comment: @Rojo The number of consecutive zero rows/columns you want to keep (I generalized the objective in the question). I forgot to add in the function call... will do now.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, yes, I know... but, I'll gloat while I still can :D

Comment: How is `z` used?

Comment: You can't any more. This only works because the sample matrix rarely has more than 2 non-zero consecutive rows. But it can be fixed

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Good catch! That was left behind from an earlier version which used `z` as a pattern. It's not needed now

Comment: Ok, I see. This is a nice code, +1.

Comment: Actually, your code produce different results from mine or @belisarius's, for some benchmarks - your matrices end up smaller.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, my last comment here is feeling ignored

Comment: @Rojo Sorry, I saw it but did not connect to this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Do you have an example of a test matrix where this gives smaller results, so that I can test it?

Comment: @rm-rf my last before last comment is feeling ignored :P

Comment: Help yourself: `m = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, 10^-3], {300, 300}]
While[removeZeroVectors[m] == 
  Transpose[Transpose[m //. rule] //. rule] == 
  Nest[rZeroVecs[Transpose@#, 2] &, m, 2],
 m = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, 10^-3], {300, 300}]]`.

Comment: Try `m={{1}, {1}, {1}}`

Comment: To fix it, you could do something like this: removeRowZeros[mat_, n_] :=
 
 Block[{z = ConstantArray[0, Last@Dimensions@mat], remove},
  remove[v : {z ..}] := Take[v, Min[n, Length@v]];
  remove[z_] := z;
  (remove /@ Split[mat])~Flatten~1];removeAllZeros[mat_, n_: 2] := 
 Nest[Transpose[removeRowZeros[#, n]] &, mat, 2]

Comment: @halmir Thanks, that's how I actually had it at first, but then removed it because the above "worked" and was slightly faster (I didn't think of the cases Rojo pointed out). Now I see that my original version would've given the correct result in all cases. I'll fix this answer later today when I have some time.

Answer (score 6):

My contribution:

```
cleanrows[m_] := 
 Delete[m, 1 + Position[ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1}, Total[Unitize@m, {2}], {3, 1}], 0]]

m2 = Transpose @ cleanrows @ Transpose @ cleanrows @ m;
```

Comment: +1, nice idea, and also seems to be the fastest so far.

Comment: Great one Simon +1

Comment: Super clever, deserves more +1...

Answer (score 5):

```
cleanAllProc[m_] := Transpose@cleanRowsProc@Transpose@cleanRowsProc@m

cleanRowsProc[m_] :=
 With[{ceroRow = ConstantArray[0, Last@Dimensions@m]},
  Module[{counter = 0, tag},
   Reap[
     Scan[
      (If[# === ceroRow , If[++counter > 2, Continue[Null, Scan]], 
         counter = 0]; Sow[#, tag]) &, m],
     tag
     ][[-1, 1]]
   ]]
```

Comment: It's good code, +1.