# Recognizing integers in an image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

This is the picture I want *Mathematica* to read[image: picture]

I want *Mathematica* to recognize these numbers and put them in a list. I know that there is a function `TextRecognize`, but I can't see how to apply it to my problem.

Since I am not familiar with image processing, I would prefer a simple solution that is easy to understand.

Any answer would appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of links that show how to get numbers out of images using `TextRecognize`: [(4464)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/can-textrecognize-read-digits), [(18683)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/applying-textrecognize-on-alpha-numerical-table), [(27045)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/improve-textrecognize-on-numbers).

Comment: @march thanks a lot !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You more or less said that you weren't interested in a "hand-made" image processing solution, but since `TextRecognize` is notoriously unreliable, I thought I'd try it anyway. `Classify` does most of the heavy lifting, so the solution isn't simple, but it's not hard to understand, either.

Ok, first step: import the image, adjust for the inhomogeneous lightning and find the individual characters:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQOAQ.jpg"]

white = Closing[img, 10];
whiteAdjusted = ImageApply[Divide, {img, white}];

components = 
 ComponentMeasurements[
   MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@whiteAdjusted], {"BoundingBox", 
    "Area"}, #2 > 10 &][[All, 2, 1]];
```

then sort the components by their left X-coordinate, i.e. from left to right (this makes it easier to just join the characters in each table cell later on).

```
components = SortBy[components, #[[1, 1]] &];
```

Next step: Train a `Classifier` to recognize digits. Since we know the font, this is much easier than the task `TextRecognize` has to do:

```
characters = Flatten[Table[
    ImageCrop[
        Rasterize[Text[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]], 
         ImageSize -> size]] -> # & /@ 
     Characters["0123456789t"], {size, {10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50}}]];

simpleOcr = Classify[characters];
```

Let's try it:

```
ImageTrim[img, #] & /@ components // GroupBy[simpleOcr] // KeySort
```

[image]

That looks very promising.

Step 3: Tell mathematica where the table grid is. It's probably possible to recognize this automatically, but if you only have this one table, that would be overkill. So I just used `LocatorPane` to move the grid to the right spot:

```
gridPts = {{85, 678}, {837, 687}, {65, 42}, {862, 48}};

LocatorPane[Dynamic[gridPts], Dynamic[Show[img,
   With[{transform = 
      Last@FindGeometricTransform[
        gridPts, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}*10 + 1.5, 
        TransformationClass -> "Perspective"]},
    Graphics[
     {Red,
      Table[Line[transform /@ {{i, 1}, {i, 12}}], {i, 12}],
      Table[Line[transform /@ {{1, i}, {12, i}}], {i, 12}]}]]]]]
```

[image]

A few definitions for readability:

This transforms image-coordinates into {row,column}-grid coordinates:

```
imageToGrid = 
  Last@FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}*10 + 
     1.5, gridPts, TransformationClass -> "Perspective"];
```

This reads a single digit given the bounding box:

```
readDigit = 
  Function[boundingBox, simpleOcr[ImageTrim[img, boundingBox]]];
```

This returns the (integer) row/column coordinates of a bounding box:

```
gridCell = 
  Function[boundingBox, Floor[imageToGrid[Mean[boundingBox]]]];
```

And this reads the full grid:

```
readGrid = 
 ToExpression[StringJoin[#]] & /@ 
  GroupBy[components, gridCell -> readDigit]
```

> <|{11, 1} -> t10, {10, 1} -> t9, {9, 1} -> t8, {8, 1} -> t7, {7, 1} ->
>      t6, {6, 1} -> t5, {5, 1} -> t4, {4, 1} -> t3, {3, 1} -> 
>     t2, {2, 1} -> t1, {11, 2} -> 5, {9, 2} -> 4, {10, 2} -> 
>     1, {8, 2} -> 2, {7, 2} -> 6, {6, 2} -> 4, {5, 2} -> 7, {4, 2} -> 
>     6, {3, 2} -> 2, {1, 2} -> t1, {2, 2} -> 6, {11, 3} -> 
>     10, {10, 3} -> 2, {9, 3} -> 7, {8, 3} -> 6, {7, 3} -> 3, {6, 3} -> 
>     2, {5, 3} -> 2, {1, 3} -> t2, {4, 3} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {2, 3} -> 
>     3, {10, 4} -> 3, {11, 4} -> 1, {4, 4} -> 10, {9, 4} -> 8, {7, 4} -> 
>     9, {8, 4} -> 1, {6, 4} -> 8, {1, 4} -> t3, {5, 4} -> 6, {3, 4} -> 
>     8, {2, 4} -> 7, {11, 5} -> 6, {10, 5} -> 4, {9, 5} -> 2, {1, 5} -> 
>     t4, {8, 5} -> 7, {7, 5} -> 7, {6, 5} -> 9, {5, 5} -> 8, {4, 5} -> 
>     3, {3, 5} -> 6, {2, 5} -> 2, {1, 6} -> t5, {11, 6} -> 2, {10, 6} -> 
>     6, {9, 6} -> 5, {8, 6} -> 5, {7, 6} -> 8, {4, 6} -> 9, {3, 6} -> 
>     8, {2, 6} -> 8, {6, 6} -> 1, {5, 6} -> 1, {8, 7} -> 10, {6, 7} -> 
>     10, {2, 7} -> 10, {1, 7} -> t6, {7, 7} -> 2, {5, 7} -> 9, {3, 7} -> 
>     9, {10, 7} -> 9, {9, 7} -> 6, {4, 7} -> 5, {11, 7} -> 7, {9, 8} -> 
>     10, {1, 8} -> t7, {3, 8} -> 5, {5, 8} -> 3, {8, 8} -> 4, {6, 8} -> 
>     3, {4, 8} -> 1, {2, 8} -> 1, {10, 8} -> 5, {7, 8} -> 1, {11, 8} -> 
>     3, {3, 9} -> 10, {1, 9} -> t8, {2, 9} -> 9, {5, 9} -> 4, {4, 9} -> 
>     7, {7, 9} -> 4, {6, 9} -> 5, {8, 9} -> 9, {9, 9} -> 9, {10, 9} -> 
>     8, {11, 9} -> 8, {5, 10} -> 10, {1, 10} -> t9, {2, 10} -> 
>     5, {3, 10} -> 7, {10, 10} -> 10, {4, 10} -> 8, {6, 10} -> 
>     6, {7, 10} -> 5, {8, 10} -> 3, {9, 10} -> 3, {11, 10} -> 
>     4, {1, 11} -> t10, {2, 11} -> 4, {7, 11} -> 10, {4, 11} -> 
>     4, {3, 11} -> 1, {6, 11} -> 7, {5, 11} -> 5, {8, 11} -> 
>     8, {10, 11} -> 7, {9, 11} -> 1, {11, 11} -> 9|>

Or, in matrix form:

```
MatrixForm[SparseArray[Normal[readGrid], Automatic, ""]]
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: +1 Very neat! I especially like the `LocatorPane` for finding the table grid

Comment: thank you I will try this tonight

Comment: At verification at first, I expected this to fail. It worked brilliantly. Great work.

Answer (score 7):

### Problem: To recognize numbers on an image and put them in a list using TextRecognize

Using the information provided in the question and comments I found the following solution.

### Solution:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQOAQ.jpg"];

  Partition[ 
  Select[ StringSplit@
    TextRecognize[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 40, {0.85, 0.07}], 
     "SegmentationMode" -> 6], NumberQ[ToExpression@#] &], 
  10]   
  (* "hint note that tesseract -psm 6 <-> SegmentationMode 6"  *)
```

### Alternative solution:

Below is an alternative solution using [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) from within Mathematica.

[image: sol]

Below are my results as you can see they are better but not perfect. There are two mistakes yet those were corrected using `expression /. "error" -> "correction"`.

[image]

Use `ToExpression` to change Strings into Integers that you can further use. Like this:

```
ToExpression /@ (Select[ StringSplit /@ Flatten[d], 
  Length@# == 11 &][[All, 2 ;;]] /. "1o" -> "10" /. "8-" -> "8" )
```

To read the tesseract's manual page from Mathematica:

```
ReadList["!man tesseract", String] //TableForm
```

This [link](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/how-ocr-works.html) could explain the limitations, uses and nature of OCR engines.

Comment: Gives errors on Mathematica 10/ Win 10 and the rows after 4th are incorrect.

Comment: @thedude I updated my answer and the alternative solution using teserract can give you a more accurate result.