# Keys in the vicinity

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, ocr

What I want to do is to recognize keys in the image and create a list of keys around every key that fall within a pentagonal (or similar) region. These are the ones that can be accidentally pressed instead of the intended key. For the following case, the keys around 'y' will be `y->{6,7,t,u g h}`. For keys at the edges there would be fewer adjacent keys. Any convenient output format will do.

[image]

I have seen [27045](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/improve-textrecognize-on-numbers), but could not get it to work with this keyboard image. To get a fresh image:

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/le9Jz.png"];
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case someone has the knowledge to take it further... The functions `ImageContents` and `ImageCases` seemed promising to me, but we'd need an entity concept for "letter" or "alphabetic character" or something like that. Both functions (without the qualifier as a second argument) find the keyboard and nothing else. I don't know if that means it can't possibly find anything else, or if it would use a different search strategy if we could tell it to look for "letter". Anyway, if we could find the letters this way, then you can find their location and use a distance function etc etc.

Comment: Will the image always be a QWERTY keyboard? In which case it might not be necessary to recognize characters.

Comment: @Melago, It is easy enough to create a list by hand, but the general task is about recognizing characters that may not be static.

Comment: Speaking of which here is a [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11408/longest-word-with-adjacent-letters-on-a-keyboard) on the Puzzling SE.

Comment: Mathematica is poor in text recognition so creating list by hand would be indeed faster than creating code that still would work only in a particular case.

Comment: This should be the simplest case. These letters are not misaligned, blurred, rotated, overlapping or otherwise obscured. I tried for a good two hours with `TextRecognize` before giving up. I will wait; perhaps someone has a method they want to share. @azerbajdzan

Comment: What font is used on the image of keyboard?

Comment: "BookAntiqua" or "BookManOldStyle"? but I could be wrong.

Comment: No, letter "g" is for example different.

Comment: maybe we can start with something like `ds = Dataset[
  TextRecognize[Binarize@ImageResize[img, 3000], 
   "Character", {"Text", "BoundingBox", "Image"}, 
   RecognitionPrior -> "Column"], MaxItems -> All]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kb = Reverse @ 
  TakeList[Characters["1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"], {10, 10, 9, 7}]; 

 vLabels = Join @@ 
  MapIndexed[{1, Sqrt[3]/2} Reverse@#2 - {(#2[[1]] - 1)/2, 0} -> # &, kb, {2}];


qwertyGraph = 
 VertexReplace[#, vLabels] & @ 
  NearestNeighborGraph[Keys @ vLabels, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

```
VertexComponent[qwertyGraph, "t", 1]
```

> ```
> {"t", "f", "g", "r", "y", "5", "6"}
> ```

```
VertexComponent[qwertyGraph, "b", 1]
```

> ```
> {"b", "v", "n", "g", "h"}
> ```

```
Select[DictionaryWordQ] @
 MapApply[StringJoin] @
  Tuples @  
   Map[VertexComponent[qwertyGraph, #, 1] &] @ 
     Characters["hello"]
```

> ```
> {"hello", "brook", "jello"}
> ```

---

**EDIT by OP**

With the dictionary available and the task enunciated in the [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11408/longest-word-with-adjacent-letters-on-a-keyboard) mentioned in the comments:

```
Clear[adjChecker];
adjChecker[k_String] := 
 And @@ (MemberQ[VertexComponent[qwertyGraph, #2, 1], #1] & @@@ 
    Partition[Characters@k, 2, 1])

Select[DictionaryLookup[], adjChecker] // SortBy[StringLength]
```

> {"a", "I", "as", "dc", "er", "es", "lo", "oi", "re", "uh", "we", 
> "ass", "awe", "dew", "ere", "err", "ewe", "huh", "loo", "lop", "oik",
> \ "poi", "pol", "pop", "red", "saw", "see", "sew", "was", "wed",
> "wee", \ "WWW", "awed", "awes", "deed", "deer", "dews", "drew",
> "ewer", \ "ewes", "free", "kook", "loll", "look", "loop", "plop",
> "poll", \ "polo", "pool", "poop", "reds", "reed", "sass", "saws",
> "seed", \ "seer", "sees", "sere", "serf", "sews", "tree", "weds",
> "weed", \ "weer", "wees", "were", "asses", "deeds", "deres", "dress",
> "erred", \ "freed", "freer", "frees", "reeds", "resew", "rewed",
> "sawed", \ "seeds", "sered", "serer", "seres", "sewed", "sewer",
> "swede", \ "treed", "trees", "tress", "trews", "wases", "weeds",
> "assert", \ "assess", "deeded", "desert", "lollop", "qwerty",
> "redder", "redrew", \ "reseed", "resews", "reweds", "sassed",
> "sasses", "seeded", "seeder", \ "seesaw", "swedes", "wedded",
> "wedder", "weeded", "weeder", \ "dessert", "dressed", "dresser",
> "dresses", "redress", "reseeds", \ "resewed", "seesaws", "tresses",
> "assessed", "assesses", "reseeded", \ "rewedded", "seesawed",
> "redressed", "redresses"}

Comment: Thanks @kglr. The graph show upside down on v12.2.0  on Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed, I am using "13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)". Does removing `Reverse` from definition of `kb` fix the issue?

Comment: No, but it flips it L-R while being upside down.

Comment: how about adding the option `VertexCoordinates -> Keys[vLabels]` in `NearestNeighborGraph`?

Comment: @kglr: Those words have nothing to do with the adjacent keys on keyboard, if that was the goal.

Comment: thank you @azerbajdzan. No idea how the list (now fixed) was concocted:)

Comment: It is fixed now. The `DictionaryWordQ` application is concise and amazing.

Comment: @kglr: The words should be words that can be written using adjacent keys. What `hello` and the outputted words have to do with it? Such word would be for example `dress`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, _"words should be words that can be written using adjacent keys"_ is an interesting requirement but I don't see that in OP. The list in the example is simply the list of dictionary words that might be typed by someone intending to type `"hello"` but accidentally hits _adjacent_ keys for each letter (the outputed words have nothing to do with the requirement as you stated).

Comment: @kglr: Ahhh... I see. There is a link in one comment of OP under OP question. - There is that requirement.

Comment: @kglr: Also... on the other hand if someone accidently hits adjacent keys then such words do not have to be in dictionary. It well could be `helkp` instead of `hello`.

Comment: I agree. In a not-too-farfetched use case for auto-correction, someone _accidentaly_ typing `"helkp"` is assumed to have meant to type one of `{"hello", "broil", "jello"}`

Answer (score 3):

Since I consider image recognizing code as a waste of time and typing keys of keyboard in sequence as pretty easy I produced the following code.

```
keyboard = 
  Characters@
   StringSplit[
    "Q W E R T Y U I O P\n A S D F G H J K L\n  Z X C V B N M", 
    "\n"];(*keys of keyboard separated and aligned with spaces*)
Grid[keyboard]
keys = DeleteCases[Flatten[keyboard], " " | "\n"];
coo = ({1, -2}*Reverse@First@Position[keyboard, #] & /@ keys);
gr = NearestNeighborGraph[coo, {All, 3}, 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[coo -> (Placed[#, Above] & /@ keys)]];
gr = VertexReplace[gr, Thread[coo -> keys]]
# -> AdjacencyList[gr, #] &@"Y"
# -> AdjacencyList[gr, #] &@"A"
# -> AdjacencyList[gr, #] &@"D"
```

[image]

```
(* "Y" -> {"T", "U", "G", "H"} *)

(* "A" -> {"Q", "W", "S", "Z"} *)

(* "D" -> {"E", "R", "S", "F", "X", "C"} *)
```

With

```
keyboard = 
  Characters@
   StringSplit[
    "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n Q W E R T Y U I O P\n  A S D F G H J K L\n \
  Z X C V B N M", "\n"];
```

[image]

```
"Y" -> {"6", "7", "T", "U", "G", "H"}

"A" -> {"Q", "W", "S", "Z"}

"D" -> {"E", "R", "S", "F", "X", "C"}
```

Comment: I would appreciate a pointer on how to use it.

Comment: I just updated :-)