# Use TextRecognize to grab timestamps from a video frame

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I have microscope videos that have a timestamp overlay to them, and it would be great if I could extract this for each frame to add to my metadata.

`TextRecognize` fails to accurately grab the numbers from the image that looks this (scaled by 4):

[image]

I have tried cropping in different ways, scaling, and several image processing methods (binarize, morphological operations, etc). I also tried prepending text to avoid the issue where `TextRecognize` does not detect the initial digits. I believe this to be a image quality problem.

I was wondering if anyone has a recommendation on how to clean this up so `TextRecognize` can detect at least the time in images like this.

Comment: Since you have a video, have you tried averaging nearby frames (assuming a high enough fps) to see if the clarity of the timestamp improves?

Comment: btw, doing this solely with TextRecognize might not be feasible, as it is a known limitation that it cannot identify disjoint letters/digits properly. A simple and robust solution might be to have templates of numbers 0-9, use `ImageCorrelate` with all 10 of them and identify which template gives you a max and its position. Since the time stamp has a structure, you can then map the digit sequence back to a time stamp.

Comment: Thank you @rm-rf. As for the averaging, because of the way the timestamp is overlaid in our microscope system, the average is of similar quality as a single image. I will try `ImageCorrelate` now.

Comment: Looks like `ImageCorrelate` will work, thanks again!

Comment: That's great! If you have a prototype of a working solution, please post it as an answer so that future visitors who have a similar problem will have a few leads to go on. This seems like a useful thing to document, as `TextRecognize` is pretty limited in what it can do.

Comment: Will do once I can. When I went to post, it told me I had to wait 8 hours since I have less than 10 reputation points.

Comment: Oh yeah, the new user restrictions are a bummer (but are useful in spam control). No hurry :) Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the timestamp will always look about the same. This allows us to crop a sample of each individual number to use as the kernel in `ImageCorrelate` (as suggested by @rm-rf).

I use the following method for the image above:

```
 (* Define Where to Crop for kernelImages *)
imageCropRows = {11, 81};
imageCropColumns = {{726, 802}, {15, 46}, {53, 120}, {433, 499}, {280,
     345}, {1033, 1105}};

(* Grab Our kernelImages *)
kernelImages = 
 ImageTake[image, imageCropRows, #] & /@ imageCropColumns
```

Ultimately, this will give a kernel set that looks like:[image]

```
(* Apply ImageCorrelate, and make maxima white points *)
imageCorrelations = (ImageCorrelate[image, #, CosineDistance] // 
      ColorNegate // Binarize[#, 0.989] &) & /@ kernelImages
```

Returns a list of images that can be further processed to extract the location in order to reassemble the digit sequence, and ultimately the timestamp. Playing with threshold value in `Binarize` will help with sensitivity.

Combining `MorphologicalComponents` and `Position` should work to find where each copy of a kernel is found. For example, say we wanted to extract the location of the 3's (kernel index 4):

```
(* Use MorpologicalComponents to identify repeated number locations *)
results = MorphologicalComponents[#] & /@ imageCorrelations;

(* Find where each copy is located *)
Mean[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ (Position[results[[4]], #] & /@ 
   Range[1, Max[results[[4]]]])
```

Once you have the pixel location of all the digits, some logic can sort them, and reconstruct the timestamp.

This can applied to an arbitrary frame with reasonable results.