# Detect numbers on the image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

How to detect numbers on the following image

[image]

I tried:

```
  img=Import["http://imgur.com/TDbn7sB.png"]

  set = ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1/20, 1/5}]] // Flatten
```

[image]

then I tried `Classify[]` but it doesn't work for large number of data,(greater than 3)

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the question [Recognizing integers in an image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102971/731)? Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27986/731) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18683/731) might help as well.

Comment: I think what that message is trying to tell you is that you have too few training samples. "The number of classes is close to the number of examples" -> you should increase the number of examples.

Comment: @C.E. I don't think the duplicates apply considering vito tries to use Machine Learning to do this

Comment: @Feyre So if I were to ask "how do I binarize an image? I tried using Binarize" that would not be a duplicate of "how do I binarize an image? I tried using ImageFilter," or what? I'm not saying that OP's attempt is a duplicate of another post, I'm saying that the question is a duplicate. If he were to make machine learning a part of the question, then the situation would be different.

Comment: @Feyre The idea with tagging the other question as a duplicate isn't that answers using machine learning aren't welcome, it's that they are just as welcome in that other question as in this one. So the situation becomes ambiguous: if someone wants to post a machine learning-based answer, in which question should he post it? That's the problem we solve by tagging questions as duplicates.