# extract dynamic values from video frames

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have a video recording the time and temperature during the experiment. I would like to ask whether it is possible for MMA to extract the above two values (highlighted in red boxes) from the frames of the video. If possible, could you please show me the related MMA functions so that I can study by myself afterwards. Right now, I have no clue if and how this can be done in MMA. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [Use TextRecognize to grab timestamps from a video frame](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27972/27951). It looks pretty similar to what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I will study that post.

Comment: If the camera is steady I'm guessing that you could simplify this problem by cropping the text from every frame. Then the problem would simply be, "can Mathematica extract the text in this image?"