# Importing numerical values from a PDF file

Tags: import, pdf-format

I need the numerical values from pdf files like this [one](http://solux.net/ies_files/SoLux%20Spectral%20Data.xls.pdf).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I use the usual `Import` command, the PDF imports, but pages of images. How can *Mathematica* be used to import the numerical values from a PDF?

Comment: It is very likely the numbers are rasterized in your PDF. In that case, `Import` alone won't cut it. Maybe run the PDF through Google Docs to extract the text.

Comment: Take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18683/193

Comment: @m_goldberg That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @belisarius neat trick, alas it produces the error "Expecting an image or graphics instead".  Checking the pdf file in Acrobat pro shows that these values are editable and so I should be able to import them.

Comment: the values seem to be in binary (??) Import["/pathto/SoLux Spectral Data.xls.pdf", "Plaintext"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Adobe Acrobat I exported the file as XML and .DOC.

The first file can be read directly using

```
Import["SoLux Spectral Data.xls.xml", "XML"]
```

but you have to cut your way through the resulting XML expression tree.

The second method involves using MS Word. After opening the .doc file, I selected the table, copied it and pasted it in the following expression:

```
ImportString["","TSV"]
```

The insertion point should be precisely in the empty string (""). After pasting, you will get this dialog box:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Press "Yes", evaluate the result and you get:

> {{"Wavelength ", "4700K ", "4100K ", "3500K "}, {280, 0.049379, 
>     0.054292, 0.0503}, {290, 0.075516, 0.037844, 0.034862}, {300, 
>     0.11254, 0.030544, 0.028027}, {310, 0.16051, 0.033413, 
>     0.029238}, {320, 0.23068, 0.067789, 0.055261}, {330, 0.32281, 
>     0.20151, 0.13953}, {340, 0.40282, 0.43615, 0.25661}, {350, 0.45898, 
>     0.57172, 0.52681}, {360, 1.2011, 0.82864, 1.3278}, {370, 1.8647, 
>     1.5222, 1.6987}, {380, 2.5338, 2.3844, 3.61}, {390, 3.5809, 4.5686, 
>     3.9927}, {400, 4.4137, 8.4548, 8.168}, {410, 5.2228, 14.205, 
>     13.863}, {420, 6.0387, 17.949, 17.46}, {430, 6.9944, 21.068, 
>     20.103}, ... }

If Word seems to copy only part of the table, try pasting it first in Excel before going to Mathematica, doing a bit of polishing there. Copying to the welcoming quotes in Mathematica will then do the trick.

Comment: @RHall Glad you like it, though I would be more pleased if a direct solution could be found.