# Extract table from image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I have the image of a matrix (download it to see it bigger):

[image: a matrix]

Is there a way to convert this into a Mathematica numerical matrix, using Mathematica?

Comment: Do you know the bounds of the values of your matrix? Are they all 0/1/-1/2?

Comment: @rm-rf Yes. You can assume that the values are all in the set `{-1, 0, 1, 2}`.

Comment: `ImageCorrelate` is probably your friend here.

Comment: Various methods are described here [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/applying-textrecognize-on-alpha-numerical-table/18971#18971). If you know the dimension of this matrix as well as how the columns are spatially distributed it might help, because a useful first step is probably to partition the image (and then use `ImageCorrelate` like rm -rf said).

Comment: @anon You can also assume that you know the dimensions of the matrix. In this example, the matrix is 46x34. The columns and rows are clearly delineated in the image.

Comment: @Anon But I don't think you can define a priori (that is, before seeing the image) where the columns are going to be.

Comment: I'd suggest [`TextRecognize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TextRecognize.html) but strangely it doesn't recognize a single digit in the image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TextRecognize` works fine after some tweaks and error corrections:

```
x = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQr6I.png"];
res = TextRecognize[Binarize[ImageResize[x, Scaled[5]], 0.7],"SegmentationMode" -> 6];

m = ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#] & /@ 
   StringSplit[
    StringReplace[
     res, {"O" | "D" | "U" -> "0", "~" | "\"" -> "-", "I" -> "1"}], 
    "\n"];

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I have used the undocumented option [`"SegmentationMode" -> 6`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31851/4678).

Comment: SegmentationMode details [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31851/2266)

Comment: @Murta My last line is clickable with the same link :)

Comment: +1 for proving that `TextRecognize` works. It seems the text needs to be large enough for it to work.

Comment: +1. But I've found one error: `m[[28,28]]` gives `-1`. It should be `1`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one way:

```
data = ColorNegate@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQr6I.png";

points=ComponentMeasurements[ MorphologicalComponents[Sharpen[Dilation[Binarize@data,1.5],1]] ,"Centroid"][[All,2]];
box=ComponentMeasurements[ MorphologicalComponents[Sharpen[Dilation[Binarize@data,1.5],1]] ,"BoundingBox"][[All,2]];

{posX,posY}=Mean/@Split[#,If[Abs[#1-#2]<5,True,False]&]&/@{Sort@points[[All,1]],Sort@points[[All,2]]}
```

We can see that grid position worked in this plot:

```
ListPlot[points,PlotRange->All,GridLines->{posX,posY},PlotStyle->Red]
```

[image]

Now let's do image partition:

```
imagePartition = ParallelMap[ImageTrim[Binarize@data, #] &, box];
```

Here is a sample:

```
imagePartition[[;; 15]]
```

[image]

Now the part that has to be improved, here is one attempt to recognize the numbers.

```
getNumber[img_]:=Module[{r,comp},
    comp=ComponentMeasurements[img,{"PerimeterCount","Holes"}][[All,2]];
    r=Which[
            Length@#==2,-1
            ,#[[1,2]]==1,0
            ,#[[1,1]]<15,1
            ,True,2
        ]&[comp];
    (*{r,comp,img}*)
    r
]
```

Two elements finds -1, one hole find 0, no hole with perimeter < 15 finds 1 and the rest is 2.

Applying it data partition as:

```
numberData=Partition[ParallelMap[getNumber,imagePartition],Length@posX]//MatrixForm
```

We get:

```
Grid[numberData,Spacings->0,Alignment-> NumberPoint,Dividers->LightGray,BaseStyle->{FontSize-> 11}]
```

[image]

Not perfect, but can be a start point. It's just improve getNumber.

### Update

With some calibration in `getNumber` and using `Binarize` intead of `Sharpen`, now all cases are ok.

Comment: Related to the last part: [coming soon. First application example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html)

Comment: Yes I know! Tks for show that this documentation is already public :)

Comment: +1 But it has some mistakes. `numberData[[6, 5]]` and `numberData[[6, 6]]` both give `0`, but should be `-1` and `1` respectively.