# What is the Java converter?

Tags: packages, java

I notice that there is a directory: `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.2\SystemFiles\Converters\Java`. What is this? I could not find any documentation either on the Wolfram site or via Google.

Also, as long as we are looking at this directory, is there documentation on using Tesseract (which is also in the directory)? I assume this is a reference to the [Tesseract OCR engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29), but could find no documentation of any related Mathematica functionality.

Comment: `TextRecognize` uses Tesseract

Comment: @mfvonh I see, so it kind of an internal resource that we use through a built-in function.

Comment: Yes, a lot of functionality is provided in this way. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31851/731) is an answer that uses tesseract itself as well as `TextRecognize`.

Comment: Per Renyi (but attributed often to Erdos), a mathematician is a type of [Java converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfr%C3%A9d_R%C3%A9nyi#cite_note-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Converters directory contains external programs and libraries that are used by `Import`/`Export` functionality.  These are meant to be accessed through builtin functions, and are not supposed to be visible (or of any concern) to users. There is no documentation because it is just an internal component of Mathematica.