# Recognizing characters with accent marks

Tags: ocr

I have written code to recognize some words, but I get errors in the recognition of some characters with accent marks. Is there any solution?

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3U9N.jpg"]
TextRecognize[i, "SegmentationMode" -> 6]
```

[image]

> ```
> 0perag5es
> Construg5es
> Tftulo
> Médulo
> ```

Comment: Im unable to force TextRecognize understanding Czech characters like "ě, š, č,..." . Adding " .. ; Language -> "Czech" " gives me exactly the same bad result as with "English", "German", or even "Portuguese". My setup - Mathematica v. 11.2.0.0 plus ThesseractTools added using the "PacletInstall" command. Can somebody test this too? Or please advice to where this has been discussed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Language -> "Portuguese"`.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3U9N.jpg"]
TextRecognize[i, "SegmentationMode" -> 6, Language -> "Portuguese"]
```

[image]

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho I have no idea.  I simply copied your code.  Where did you get it from?

Comment: This link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/applying-textrecognize-on-alpha-numerical-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho If you follow the link there, it is explained what it does ... see the screenshot with green text in Murta's post.