# Rotate a grid, made up of lines, so that it aligns with the xy axes

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

While working on an answer for [another problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23560/how-to-detect-crosses-and-circles-in-60x60-raster-images#23560) I hit upon one of my own.

I took the image given in that question and cleaned it up so that I could detect the grid lines:

```
i = ColorNegate@
  Binarize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbTGY.jpg"], .99]

lines = ImageLines[
   Image[ImageData@Dilation[i, 0.5] - 
   ImageData@DeleteBorderComponents@Dilation[i, 0.5]]
];

Show[i, Graphics[{Thick, Green, Line /@ lines}]]
```

[image: the image with the lines marked]

From here I would like to rotate the grid so that the they are absolutely vertical and horizontal. The original picture looks like a scanned piece of paper and I imagine it could be rotated more than this sample is.

My attempt was to separate the horizontal lines from the vertical lines:

```
hor = Select[lines, #[[1, 1]] == 0 &];
ver = Reverse[Select[lines, #[[2, 2]] == 0 &], 2];
```

Then I would like to find a transfer function that will bring the end point of each horizontal line to the same y value that the starting point has, and respectively for the vertical lines.

So my fruitless attempt to do that looks like this:

```
pts = {Join[Transpose[Apply[{#, 0} &, ver, {2}]][[1]], 
   Transpose[Apply[{0, #2} &, hor, {2}]][[1]]], 
  Join[Transpose[Apply[{#, 0} &, ver, {2}]][[2]], 
   Transpose[Apply[{0, #2} &, hor, {2}]][[2]]]}
pts // MatrixForm
```

[image: how the matrix looks]

And then

```
transf = FindGeometricTransform[pts[[1]], pts[[2]]][[2]];
newLines = transf@# & /@ lines;
Show[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i, transf, DataRange -> Full], 
 Graphics[{Thick, Green, Line /@ newLines, Yellow, Line /@ lines}]]
```

It returns errors and I don't get the rotation I'm looking for.

[image: final result]

Any ideas are welcome as long as they start from the lines that I have. It may be possible to find the grid in a different way and perhaps then the procedure to find the rotation would not be the same.

Comment: Have you seen this?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5695/121

Comment: I'm not sure which part of that problem is relevant since it seems a lot more advanced. I did get the idea of using `FindGeometricTransform` from another answer, but I don't seem to have understood it properly: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image

Comment: I'm not sure either, it's just the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple method that seems to work. Call the grid above `img`. Find the best/strongest line in the image:

```
lines = ImageLines[img, MaxFeatures -> 1]
```

We'll need the slope of this line - here's a function to do that

```
slope[s_, e_] := ArcTan@@(e - s);
```

(shorter version thanks to nikie). This can be applied as

```
slopeLine = First[slope @@@ lines]
```

For this image, we get a slope of -0.00943421. So now rotate the image back through this value:

```
ImageRotate[img, -slopeLine]
```

which straightens it up reasonably well. Here's the strongest line in the image (the orange one)

[image]

and here is the rotated image:

[image]

Comment: +1. `slope` could be made shorter: `slope[s_, e_] := ArcTan @@ (e - s)`

Comment: @nikie thanks, I'll add that to the answer...

Answer (score 12):

If you have v9, here's an alternative solution: first I calculate the gradient and gradient orientation for each pixel

```
gray = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
orientation = GradientOrientationFilter[gray, 3];
gradient = GradientFilter[gray, 3];
```

then I create a weighted histogram from those:

```
wd = WeightedData[Flatten[ImageData[orientation]], 
   Flatten[ImageData[gradient]]];
hd = SmoothKernelDistribution[wd];
Plot[Evaluate[PDF[hd, x]], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image: weighted histogram plot]

since the kernel histogram is a smooth function, I can use `FindMaximum` to find the orientation with the largest total weight:

```
max = FindMaximum[Evaluate[PDF[hd, x]], {x, 0}]
```

=> {0.712209, {x -> -0.0118227}}

And then rotate the image around that angle:

```
ImageRotate[img, -x /. max[[2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfect ! Thanks but FindMaximum takes long time to evaluate... Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to @bills's answer you can rotate by the mean of the slope of all the detected lines.

```
slopeLine = slope @@@ lines
meanslope = 
 Mean@Join[Select[slopeLine, # > -1 &], 
   Select[slopeLine, # < -1 &] + Pi/2]
ImageRotate[img, -meanslope]
```

[image]