# Mathematica output in ASCII or larger text size for the output?

Tags: output-formatting, text, rasterize

I am trying to read the output of this [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23562/2000) that has crosses, circles and spaces. For some reason, the output is in very-very small alphabets so I would like to get it in ASCII and/or in larger alphabets to be more easily readable.

[image]

So

> 1. how can I get Mathematica output in ASCII let say with the earlier style table having only crosses, circles and spaces?
> 2. is there some setting to control the output formatting to specify the size of writing such as the crosses, circles and errs? Are there
>      environment variables to adjust the size of the writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `ImageCompose` isn't working the same way across the versions, with regard to scaling.  You could try either `Style[f2@#, Red, 80]` by itself or changing the final line to:

```
Map[Show[Rasterize@#, Graphics@Text[Style[f2@#, Red, 80], {59, 59}]] &, 
  grid, {2}] // GraphicsGrid
```

Comment: Worked fine with 40 instead of 80 +1, now I want to turn it into text file so I could read the output in my favourite editor ...this is under investigation: `img = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/NbTGY.jpg"]; grid = ImagePartition[ ImageCrop[ImageRotate[img, 0.7 \[Degree]], {1180, 720}, {-0.15, 0.2}], {118, 119}]; Table[similarity[i, {{x, o, empty}, {"x", "o", " "}}], {i, grid}]`, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/textrecognize-with-crosses-circles-and-spaces-results-into-oddities-why?lq=1, a mistake with traversing.