# Slice a mathematica image into sub images along black straight lines?

Tags: image-processing

I have a tic tac toe board I want to dynamically process in mathematica to have my robot play a user in tic tac toe. In order to determine the users move, I want to slice the board into 9 images, which are the 9 boxes of the board. How can I slice this image of the board into 9 boxes representing each space where there can be a move?

[image: example board]

The image has white space and therefore using imagePartition produces something like:

[image]

This is because the boxes are not perfect squares, and the board is not perfectly in the center of the image.

Additionally, here is an example of the board that our delta robot draws:
[image]

Comment: How would I use that to slice directly along the lines thought? Additionally how do I store each image in an array of images?

Comment: Imagine a Tic Tac Toe board. I want to slice exactly along the lines so I can see what is in each position

Comment: So the board may not be perfect, we are processing it with a webcam

Comment: You should post sample images

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Detecting grid lines in a raster image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13918/detecting-grid-lines-in-a-raster-image)

Comment: Another: [How to detect crosses and circles in 60x60 raster images?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23560/how-to-detect-crosses-and-circles-in-60x60-raster-images)

Comment: Once I detect those grid lines however, how can I partition the image into segments to evaluate individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Framed[i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTeBU.png"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ib = ColorNegate@Binarize@i;
sc = SelectComponents[ib, "Count", -1];
bb = ComponentMeasurements[sc, "BoundingBox"];
bs = Reverse[Sort /@ {#[[1]], Last@ImageDimensions@sc - #[[2]]} &@ Transpose[bb[[1, 2]]]];
it = ImageTake[sc, Sequence @@ bs];
it1 = ImageTake[i, Sequence @@ bs];
eps = MorphologicalTransform[Thinning@it, "EndPoints"];
nw = NestWhile[ImageTake[#, {2, -2}, {2, -2}] & /@ # &, {it1, it, eps}, 
   ComponentMeasurements[#[[3]], "Mask", "BorderComponents" -> False] =!= {} &];

Partition[Framed /@ (ImageMultiply[nw[[1]], #] & /@ (Erosion[#, 1] & /@ Image /@
              (ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@nw[[2]], "Mask"][[All, 2]]))), 3] //
              Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why does mine return this? http://postimg.org/image/lain5m35t/

Comment: Additionally, why do the marks change locations from the original board?

Comment: Probably because you forgot my first line

Comment: These are the exact same commands copied and pasted: http://postimg.org/image/jxj8731p1/

Comment: Are you running Mathematica 10?

Comment: Nope, Mathematica V9 here

Comment: Do you know why the symbols change location in your example?

Answer (score 4):

One way to approach this is to use a Watershed algorithm to segment the image. Each of the watersheds contains one of the symbols.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTeBU.png"];
waterI = WatershedComponents[i];
waterI // Colorize
```

[image]

You can then separate out the three symbols

```
{m1, m2, m3, m4} = ComponentMeasurements[waterI, "Mask"];
{ImageMultiply[Image[Normal[m1[[2]]]], i], 
 ImageMultiply[Image[Normal[m3[[2]]]], i], 
 ImageMultiply[Image[Normal[m4[[2]]]], i]}
```

[image]