# Importing a grid of numbers from an image (sudoku like)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-networks, ocr, recreational-mathematics

Can anyone see a way to import a grid of numbers from

http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/2019/puzzle/lantern_festival.html

into Mathematica? `TextRecognize` doesn't seem to directly work

[image]

Comment: Similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916732/mathematicas-textrecognize-not-up-to-par

Comment: Check [18683](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18683/5478), [4464](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4464/5478) and related topics for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried a few solutions, they seem to be kind of brittle, rely on matching the font. https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/slitherinks.nb . Didn't expect to be reimplementing OCR in 2020 ....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## 1 - Summary of a simple solution

In this particular DIGIT case there is a very simple solution based on neural nets (NNs)trained on MNIST Data. It is just a few lines of code:

```
i=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2c2.png"];
imageGRID = ImagePartition[i, Scaled[1/22]];
lenet = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"];
test[x_] := If[ImageDistance[imageGRID[[2, 2]], x] > 10, lenet[x], "-"]
Grid[imageGRID /. x_Image :> test[x] /. 7 -> 1, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

## 2 - How it wroks

Now let's go in detail about it. In Wolfram NN repo there are 2 directly relevant NNs (as of today):

- [LeNet Trained on MNIST Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/LeNet-Trained-on-MNIST-Data)
- [CapsNet Trained on MNIST Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/CapsNet-Trained-on-MNIST-Data)

I will go with the simplest - LeNet, let's get it from the repo:

```
lenet = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"];
```

Next get this image:

[image]

```
i=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2c2.png"];
```

Now - partition it into an a matrix of sub-images -- one sub-image per digit. Your image got 22 boxes vertically and horizontally - so this is how you do it:

```
imageGRID = ImagePartition[i, Scaled[1/22]]
```

[image]

Now we can run LeNet on recognizing the digits, but we got a few little problems here.

- LeNet is not trained on blank images - images without digits - it always expects a digit. So if you feed it blank it will make up a closest possible digit it thinks it corresponds to. So we need a way to test for blanks. THere are many ways - but let's just use a this test (where `imageGRID[[2, 2]]` is a sample blank image):

  ```
  test[x_] := If[ImageDistance[imageGRID[[2, 2]], x] > 10, lenet[x], "-"]
  ```
- Another problem - LeNet can get confused with some of the typed digits. It will think 1 is a 7 actually due to the font chosen in your original image. This depends on specific images and fonts and can be customary hot-fixed. To avoid hacks I use here, you can train your own LeNet easily on the digits fo your type. Docs have a lot of examples about it.

So here is your final result:

```
Grid[imageGRID /. x_Image :> test[x] /. 7 -> 1, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

So simple with modern AI :-) And actually you can train a NN to take your original image grid and return a matrix of values. Maybe image2image nets' architecture would be interesting to try to adopt for this, as matrix is just another image; you can find those nets in Wolfram NN repo.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, SVHN trained digit recognizer in wolfram library may be useful -- http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/

Comment: I like your solution!  If the original image had a 7, your last replacement would cause problems.  It would be great to start with pre-trained MNIST and extend it in this case for the blank and for the 7 versus 1.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a semi-manual way to do it :

Importation of the image, cutting it in a 48X48 array of small images,
removing the borders :

```
imageArray = img  //
   RightComposition[
    ImagePartition[#, 40, 40] &
    , Map[Binarize, #, {2}] &
    , Map[ImageCrop[#, 38] &, #, {2}] &
    ];
(* a view of a piece of the array :  *)  
imageArray[[10 ;; 15, 5 ;; 10]] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Then regrouping with `FindCluster[#,5]` (5 because we want 5 groups),
removing exact duplicates (with `Union`) and see the result :

```
imageArray //
 RightComposition[
  Flatten
  , FindClusters[#, 5] &
  , (Union /@ # &)
  , Column[Row /@ #, Dividers -> All] &
  ]
```

[image]

There's no errors, so one can manually create the correspondances between the groups of images and the numbers :

```
  rules = {1 -> "-", 2 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 5 -> 0}
```

The final result :

```
 imageArray //
 RightComposition[
  ClusteringComponents[#, 5] &
  , # /. rules  &
  , Grid]
```

[image]
      ]

Comment: I don't know how FindClusters works, but it's probably less "black box magic" than NN.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the solution of Vitaliy Kaurov and using his initial code to import the image and create the imageGRID, I came up with the following:

```
representativeDigits = 
 Association[{imageGRID[[1, 1]] -> "-", imageGRID[[1, 7]] -> 1, 
   imageGRID[[1, 8]] -> 3, imageGRID[[1, 10]] -> 2, 
   imageGRID[[1, 12]] -> 0}];
Grid[Partition[
  representativeDigits[
     First@Nearest[Keys@representativeDigits, #]] & /@ 
   Flatten@imageGRID, 22], Frame -> All]
```

No neural net, just using "Nearest" and giving it some values that show what we are seeing.  Not nearly as fun as using a neural network but kind of nice too.  Of course, it won't work if there aren't examples of each of the digits we want.